# Saving a file from wget with different name

Tags: linux, wget

When I download from wget it get save automatically with default name but I want to rename it while downloading itself. 
I also tried wget -O but it didn't work. Could someone please have me updated?

Comment: What exactly did you try, and what happened instead? `-O` is the option that *should* work.

Comment: [wget -O c:\bin\super.html http://superuser.com/questions/1178556/
saving-a-file-from-wget-with-different-name](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)

Comment: I voted to close as "too broad" because "didn't work" is vague.

Answer (score 0):

How about curl -o?
It's an alternative.